# using a .sh script for docker healthchecks

Tags: bash, docker

sitting on that problem for like 2 hours now and iam getting crazy

here is the example bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 0;
```

here is the dockerfile:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=2s CMD HealthCheckTest.sh || exit 1
```

I still get always unhealthy.

Want i want to do is have some logic inside my bash script to determine if the container is healthy or not.

Comment: Any reason why not `HEALTHCHECK --interval=2s CMD bash HealthCheckTest.sh` ?

Comment: it works now thank you. Every tutorial is using curl and never used a bash script i had to try stuff out

Comment: @Loading hey, I'm also having the same issue. how did you get it to work if you dont mind sharing?

Comment: as far as i remember it was with the way i called the script. Something like that (just out of my head)

HEALTHCHECK --interval=2s CMD bash "HealthCheckTest.sh || exit 1"

Answer (score 7):

7,000 views and no accepted answer in 4 years, figured it was still a valid question for those learning.

**TL;DR** The script is likely not in the container's shell `$PATH`, so Docker's HEALTHCHECK can't find it without passing a full or relative path.

*Here's an example of the original question, recreating the failure (without the `|| exit 1` operator masking the exit):*

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

ADD --chmod=777 HealthCheckTest.sh .

HEALTHCHECK --interval=2s CMD HealthCheckTest.sh
```

HealthCheckTest.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

exit 0;
```

Then build it with `docker build --tag nginx-healthcheck-broken .`

The container will run (`docker run nginx-healthcheck-broken`), but if you type `docker ps` in another terminal, you'll see it says `(unhealthy)` under status. You can check why it's failing by using `docker inspect <container sha>` and look for Health, it may look like this:

```json
            "Health": {
                "Status": "unhealthy",
                "FailingStreak": 54,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-04-14T15:26:44.650809765-07:00",
                        "End": "2023-04-14T15:26:44.70105688-07:00",
                        "ExitCode": 1,
                        "Output": "/bin/sh: 1: HealthCheckTest.sh: not found\n"
                    },
```

The fix is to add the path to execute it, in this example the file is in the current working directory, so you can execute it with a `./`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

ADD --chmod=777 HealthCheckTest.sh .

HEALTHCHECK --interval=2s CMD ./HealthCheckTest.sh
```

Now rebuild: `docker build --tag nginx-healthcheck-fixed .`

Docker should now show that the container's HEALTHCHECK status is healthy, in `docker ps` and `docker inspect <container sha>`:

```json
            "Health": {
                "Status": "healthy",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-04-14T15:49:08.384675853-07:00",
                        "End": "2023-04-14T15:49:08.426373825-07:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    },
```

---

PS The reason for the `|| exit 1`, comes from the [Dockerfile reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck).

Docker is expecting the HEALTHCHECK exit code to be either 0 (success), or 1 (unhealthy), while 2 apparently is reserved for future use. In most shells, a `||` operator is an OR statement, similar to an if statement, specifically if the previous command fails (any none zero exit), run this next. Adding the `|| exit 1` will mask the previous failure, and ensure the exit code for a failure is always a 1.

This makes more sense if you consider the command for the HEALTHCHECK might not be just a script, say like `curl` which exits with a 6, if the domain is non existent. The downside is that it masks the original exit code.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use Compose health check if you use Docker Compose:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck

Also you can define your health checks in a bash script which can be called using `ENTRYPOINT` in `Dockerfile`, e.g.:

https://github.com/ledermann/docker-rails/blob/develop/docker/wait-for-services.sh